# Powershell - DC Locator Script to retrieve available domain Controller

Tags: powershell, domaincontroller

I am integrating Active Directory connector with a tool where I must enter below format of URI to connect :

```
ldaps://domainController1.domain.testdomain.local:636/
```

If the given domain controller is not active, a DC locator script is available to configure a high-availability connection to Active Directory. This script should returns with the available Active Domain Controller list so it can be used by the AD connector.

By looking at some documentation, I wrote the below script

```
Script=(get-addomaincontroller -DomainName 'domain.testdomain.local' -Discover).hostname
```

This script returns the below map of available domain controller :

```
[{"Objectreturned":"availableDC.domain.testdomain.local","Length":"24"}]
```

Unfortunately, even if the script retrieves correctly an active domain controller, I am not able to connect since I think the tool except the first given format.

Is there any other PS script that could format the available DC as shown URI ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need a bit of string formatting:

```
$domainName = 'domain.testdomain.local'
$DC = Get-ADDomainController -DomainName $domainName -Discover 

return 'ldaps://{0}:636/' -f $DC.Hostname[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I've tried it but unfortunately it is still not working on the tool so I'll request further help from the developers.